# how to create $_GET['id]?

Tags: php, json, api

I've got this url that i need to be parsed to a mypage.php=id=?z1k93m9jg7gvv73
To then extract the data and layout as I need. My experience with this sort of stuff is very limited, searched around for a good hour with not much clarity.

```
http://www.tickster.com/sv/api/0.2/events/z1k93m9jg7gvv73
```

So my question is how would I best implant this ? I guess i will use `apiUri` to manipulate it?

```
"id": "z1k93m9jg7gvv73",
  "name": "Thomas Stenström på the Crypt, Linköping",
  "start": "2017-03-25T20:00:00+01:00",
  "end": "2017-03-26T01:00:00+01:00",
  "infoUri": "http://www.tickster.com/sv/events/z1k93m9jg7gvv73/2017-03-25/thomas-stenstrom-pa-the-crypt-linkoping",
  "shopUri": "https://secure.tickster.com/Intro.aspx?ERC=Z1K93M9JG7GVV73",
  "apiUri": "http://www.tickster.com/sv/api/0.2/events/z1k93m9jg7gvv73",
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title so something that isn't a mere repetition of the tags. If you remove *API*, *JSON* and *PHP* , all of which are in the tags and are just redundant, it leaves *how to create $_GET['id]*, which conveys absolutely zero meaning regarding the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your title should be descriptive enough to be of use to future readers here who see it in a search result.

Comment: You did see the 7000 previous posts here that I found by searching for *php parse JSON*?

Comment: The parsing part is not what's bothering, it's how to properly

create a event.php=?z1k93m9jg7gvv73 the data within is no problem.

Comment: You may want to improve your question to make it more clear what you're asking, then (as I suggested before).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get the hang of it don't know if it's the right way

```
    # Define $getbase variable
    echo $getbase = isset($_GET['system']) ? $_GET['system'] : "No ID!";
```

gets me as far as http://blackfyre.se/index.php?system

using switch case `switch($getbase)`

on the page with the API data that for each id I use

```
$id = "$getbase";
$json_array = file_get_contents("http://www.tickster.com/sv/api/0.2/events/{$id}?key=KEY
```

So far so good! but I've got to use URL

```
http://blackfyre.se/index.php?system=87a7txz1655p0k8
```

What i really want is somthing like `index.php?system&event=87a7txz1655p0k8`